# How can I have the text-align in the middle for 0% in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I currently have a progress bar that looks like this which I've achieved with bootstrap.

For some reason the 0/0 goes to the left and `text-align: center;` isn't working to make the text go to the middle.

It's interesting to note that also `0/0` is not displaying but instead I'm getting `0` even though when I look in the console I can see that `0/0` is there.

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this so the `0/0` appears in the center?

[image: progress bars]

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row justify-content-center">
  <div class="col-xs-1">☹️</div>
  <div class="col-xs-8">
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" style="width: test_number_percentage" aria- valuenow="test_number_percentage" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="7">
        0 / 7
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-1" style="padding-left: 0;"></div>
</div>
```

test_number percentage is equal to 0% if 0 or 100% if 7
test_number is either 0 or 7 depending on the bar.

Comment: The progress bar has `width: 0` by default. You can override this but it will add the background-color...

Comment: can you give link of jsfiddel or codepen ?

Comment: I made a mistake with the width and it's explained and edited now. Apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it'll helps you:

```css
.left {
      padding-right: 0;
      text-align: right;
    }
    .right{
      padding-left: 0;
    }
    .justify-content-center {
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .progress{
      margin-bottom: 0;
      color:black;
      text-align: center;
      position: relative;
    }
    .progress_text {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      color: #fff;
      z-index: 1;  
    }
```

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-xs-2 left">
            <img src="https://image.ibb.co/dw0DAG/sad.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" style="width: calc(test_number*100%/7)" aria- valuenow="test_number" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="7">
                </div>
                <span class="progress_text">test_number / 7</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 right">
            <img src="https://image.ibb.co/eonoub/happy.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And when you have 7/7 it shows you:

```css
    .left {
      padding-right: 0;
      text-align: right;
    }
    .right{
      padding-left: 0;
    }
    .justify-content-center {
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .progress{
      margin-bottom: 0;
      color:black;
      text-align: center;
      position: relative;
    }
    .progress_text {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      color: #fff;
      z-index: 1;  
    }
```

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
       <div class="col-xs-2 left">
          <img src="https://image.ibb.co/dw0DAG/sad.png" />
       </div>
       <div class="col-xs-8">
          <div class="progress">
             <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" 
                role="progressbar" style="width: calc(7*100%/7)" aria-
                valuenow="7" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="7">
             </div>
                <span class="progress_text">7 / 7</span>
          </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-xs-2 right">
          <img src="https://image.ibb.co/eonoub/happy.png" />
       </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. Adding progress_text to css worked.

Comment: Great! You're welcom. Check and up answer as "this answer is useful" pls. @alexia

Answer (score 0):

you are putting the text inside the progress-bar div but you have to put it on the progress div

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
   <div class="col-xs-1">☹️</div>
   <div class="col-xs-8">
      <div class="progress">
         <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" 
            role="progressbar" style="width: test_number" aria-
            valuenow="test_number" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="7">
         </div>
            test_number / 7
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-1" style="padding-left: 0;"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/99azq2ay/1/

Comment: I've tried your way and it kinda works and kinda doesn't.

The 0/7 appears and is in the middle. But for 7/7 it is behind the green somewhere and doesn't show.